# jQuery cookie and replace function in C#

Tags: jquery, cookies, replace

I'm creating a cookie with jQuery and, in IE 7, saving codes with "," to separate them, I receive the following message:

"Is not possible obtain value of the property 'replace': the object is null or not defined"

```
$.cookie(
    "CompareList", 
    $.cookie("CompareList").replace("," + id + ",", ""), 
    { path: "/" }
);
```

TKX, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your cookie doesn't exist yet, you can't read its value and do stuff to it. From looking at the [cookie plugin source](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) it returns null (not an empty string) if there's no such cookie, so "replace" will fail. How about

```
var cookie = $.cookie("CompareList");
if (cookie) {
    $.cookie("CompareList",cookie.replace("," + id + ",", ""), 
    { path: "/" });
}
```

Your replace snippet looks pretty suspect also. That is going to replace a string of form `",someid,"` with an empty string, is that really what you want?